# Сравнение null vs object

Tags: javascript

Почему `null === null // true ?`

Ведь два одинаковых объекта никогда не равны друг другу.

```
typeof(null) // object
typeof({})   // object
{} === {}    // false
```

Comment: `var a = {}; var b = a; a === b` вернёт `true`

Comment: Да, если сравнивать два объекта по ссылке, получается true.

Comment: `null` тоже можно воспринимать как ссылку на специальный объект, символизирующий пустое значение :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

null это один объект

> Значение null является литералом JavaScript, представляющим нулевое или «пустое» значение, то есть, когда нет никакого объектного значения. Это одно из примитивных значений JavaScript.

[Полное описание null](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)

Comment: если это цитата, не плохо было бы добавить ссылку на источник

Comment: @Grundy согласен. Добавил.